# Automatic CAN bus termination

Tags: resistors, can

I have two CAN busses which are each terminated on each end by a 120Ω resistor, as shown in the diagram below. The CAN bus consists of a `CAN high`, `CAN low` and `ground` connection. To terminate it, a 120Ω resistor connects `CAN high` and `CAN low`.

[image: CAN bus setup]

Sometimes I want to use both CAN busses completely separate but in some situations, I want to connect the devices *D3* and *D4* together, making a single bigger CAN bus.

To connect the two, I need to remove the two resistors *R2* and *R3* and then connect the CAN bus together.
My CAN connection currently terminates in a D-SUB connector *X1* (at each end *D1*, *D3*, *D4*, *D6*) to easily connect other CAN devices. At the same time I have a switch (*S1*) that will enable or disable the CAN bus termination, as can be seen in the schematic below.

[image: Simplified schematic]

What I want to do is to remove the manual operation of the switch *S1* by including something in the D-Sub connector *X1*. When nothing is connected to it, the terminating resistor *R1* will connect `CAN high` and `CAN low`. But when I connect another device to the connector *X1*, the resistor *R1* will not connect `CAN high` and `CAN low` anymore.

I would appreciate any tips that point me towards a possible solution. I should also mention that connecting and disconnecting any device will happen when everything is powered off and does not need to happen during operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you *must* do is to fix your incorrect connector pin-out and turn it into CAN. DB9 connectors for CAN are widely standardized and professional engineers follow industry standards. You should have CANHI=7, CANLO=2, GND=3.

Once you have turned your pin-out into CAN, the simplest solution might be to buy pre-made DB9 terminators and plug those in whenever you don't connect the buses together. For example these: https://www.kvaser.com/product/kvaser-d-sub-9-pin-120-ohm-termination-adapter-2/ (though Kvaser specifically are ridiculously expensive - there's plenty of 2nd source doing the same thing for a 10th of the price).

Alternatively, you could also connect two pins of the DB9 connector together at each end (to once again violate the standard pin-out...) and then have that signal activate an analog switch, which in turn enables the resistor on that board only. Larger BOM but cheaper external adapters.